# Access Textbox control source outside current report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2016, dynamic-text

I am creating a Report in MS Access 2016. I want textboxes showing a summary of data from other tables - without actually showing rows of those tables (no subreports if possible). For example, I have tried to create a textbox with formula

```
 =Format(Avg([WeekData].[DIFOT]),"##0.0%") & " DIFOT This Week"
```

which should return something like

```
100% DIFOT This Week
```

(NB `Weekdata` is a query and `DIFOT` is a field in that query, all in the same database as this report.)

However instead it just gives me `#Error`.
Please can you tell me the most efficient way to pull together summary figures such as these without creating any more queries and/or subreports than absolutely necessary? I'm quite new to SQL and Access on the whole.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what Domain Aggregate Functions are for. Suggest you research that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DAvg() domain aggregate function. Also, the ## characters in Format() pattern serve no purpose.

`=Format(DAvg("DIFOT", "WeekData"), "0.0%") & " DIFOT This Week"`

or

`=Format(DAvg("DIFOT", "WeekData"), "Percent") & " DIFOT This Week"`